# How to filter attribute values in XML file?

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

Consider the below xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RootElement>
  <HomeSite>
    <Context enabled="1" active="1">
      <Culture>en-us</Culture>
      <Affiliate>0</Affiliate>
      <EmailAddress>sreetest@test.com</EmailAddress>
      <Password>sreesree1</Password>
    </Context>
  <Context enabled="0" active="1">
      <Culture>en-us</Culture>
      <Affiliate>0</Affiliate>
      <EmailAddress>sreetest@test.com</EmailAddress>
      <Password>sreesree1</Password>
    </Context>
  </HomeSite>
</RootElement>
```

At present I am doing

```
string applicationType="HomeSite";
    XDocument xmlSkuDescDoc = null;
    xmlSkuDescDoc = XDocument.Load(@"D:\Config.xml");
    var newContextElementCollection = new List<ContextElements>();
     //get the property and values
    (from data in xmlSkuDescDoc.Descendants(applicationType)
     select data)
     .Descendants("Context")
     .Elements()
     .ToList()
     .ForEach(i => newContextElementCollection.Add(new ContextElements { Property = i.Name.ToString(), Value = i.Value }));
```

Where

```
public class ContextElements
{
    public string Property { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Now a new requirement has come where I need to pick up records for those context whose attribute value is **enabled="1".**

So how to do so?

Help needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this:

```
xmlSkuDescDoc.Descendants("Context")
                .Where(el => el.Attribute("enabled").Value == "1")
                .Elements()
                .ToList()
                .ForEach(i => newContextElementCollection.Add(new ContextElements { Property = i.Name.ToString(), Value = i.Value }));
```